# Can access router settings via Wifi but not on a wired connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, dd-wrt

On my Netgear WNR2000v3 running DD-WRT I can access the setting panel via Wifi but not on a wired connection why is this? I need it to connect to ethernet to flash the default firmware back via TFTP.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: On windows it says Unidentified network and no network access. And when I try to go to 192.168.1.1 it will not load on the wired connection.

Comment: you probably aren't getting an IP, if you know how, check your dhcp server on the router while you are in the settings on wifi.

Comment: The dhcp server is enabled.

Comment: Are you getting a network connection when you plug into the router?

Comment: No. I am still unable to get a connection.

Comment: is your machine configured to manually or automatically pick up an ip from the network (on your Ethernet card)?

Comment: I have had it set up with both a static ip and a dynamic ip and no matter what way it is set up will not connect.

Comment: Double check that you are connecting to a switch port and not the WAN or uplink port

Comment: I am connected to the a switch port.

Answer (score 1):

DD-WRT is a very sophisticated firmware and users can easily disrupt the working of the router with incorrect settings. Since you plan to reflash the router back to stock,  you might as well do a hard 30-30-30 reset. The fresh reset should solve your lan connectivity problem.

Comment: I have tried many 30-30-30 resets with no luck.

Comment: Do you have another pc to try from? Preferably use a static ip.

Comment: I will try from another pc as I have not done that yet. I have used a static ip with all of my attempts however.